# Mat-Table dinamica incluso el encabezado de cada columna

Tags: table, angular-material, tabla-dinámica, mat-table

Hola estoy tratando de armar una dataTable (mat-table) de angular material con un objeto formado de varias tablas de la BD que me mandan desde el backend. El objeto que me llega es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que me trae el response.dato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el encabezado de cada columna también lo podría sacar del objeto (response.title):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi idea es insertar esos datos en la mat table donde el .ts es:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSourcePageEvent } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { CdkTableModule }  from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { PayrollServices } from 'src/app/services/payroll.services';
import { global } from 'src/app/services/global';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-payroll',
  templateUrl: './payroll.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payroll.component.css'],
  providers: [PayrollServices]
})
export class PayrollComponent {
  public url;
  public data :any;
  public array: any;
  public columnas: string[]=[];

  

  constructor(
    private _payrollServices: PayrollServices
  ) {
    this.url = global.url;
   }

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.getPosts(); 
  }

  getPosts(){
    this._payrollServices.getPosts().subscribe(
      response =>{
        this.data= response;
        this.columnas = response.title;

        console.log(this.columnas);
        console.log(this.data);   
      },
      error =>{
        console.log(error)
      }
    )
  }


}
```

Y el HTML es el siguiente:

```
<div>
        <table mat-table [dataSource]= "data" class="mat-elevation-z4">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="columna" *ngFor="let columna of columnas">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{columnas}}</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element[columnas]}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnas"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnas" ></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Pero me da los siguientes errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado información sobre lo que estoy queriendo hacer y no encuentro. Lo que encuentro siempre dejan al menos el encabezado de cada columna fijo, y necesito que todo sea dinámico. Si alguien tiene solución para esto le voy a estar muy agradecido.
PD: Perdón si estoy cometiendo algún error fulero, hace poco empecé a programar y menos tiempo que estoy con angular material. :)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te está fallando el tipo de dato, estás enviando una colección de objetos y está esperando un string.
Prueba convirtiendo la variable de tu array antes de pasarla al material con:

```
 getPosts(){
this._payrollServices.getPosts().subscribe(
  response =>{
    this.data= response;
    this.columnas = response.title;
    this.columnas = JSON.stringify(this.columnas)

    console.log(this.columnas);
    console.log(this.data);   
  },
  error =>{
    console.log(error)
  }
)
```

}

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta. Si lo convierte en un string, pero no lo puedo recorrer en el HTML para generar las columnas. A no ser que sepas otra manera.